# Animate last added child in Grid View with Adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a `GridView` which I am constantly adding views to. When the view adds to the grid I wish for it to do an animation. However, as I have to use `setAdapter()` to refresh the `GridView`, it ends up animating all views, as they are all being re-added. Is there anyway around this?

Here is the code for my view I am adding:

```
public class GridImageView extends ImageView {


public GridImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public GridImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public GridImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0,1,0,1);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    this.startAnimation(anim);
 }
}
```

As always, thanks for your help

Comment: In the `getView()` method of the adapter you could see if you're at the last position and somehow signal that to the `ImageView` that it should animate itself.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work nicely. Will post my solution,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luksprog's suggestion, I have set a flag in my custom view which will determine if the view should animate when added to the Grid View.

```
public class GridImageView extends ImageView
{

   private boolean _animate = false;
   public GridImageView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public GridImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public GridImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onAttachedToWindow() {

       if(_animate){

            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0,1,0,1);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            this.startAnimation(anim);
       }
   }


   public void set_animate(boolean _animate) {
       this._animate = _animate;
   }
```

}

and my adapter in its `GetView()` function checks if it is the last in the array list, and sets the flag to true if so.

```
    if( i == ( _gridDetailsArrayList.size() - 1 ))
        holder.gridImage.set_animate(true);
```